# How to mail mp4 file from Android mobile

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to mail a captured video stored in SDCard . How can we attach an mp4 file to mail.
Can any one help me how to code to mail an mp4 file  by attaching it to mail.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).setType("audio/wav").setType("image/jpeg").setType("message/rfc822")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strDetails).putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris).putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, strAudioFilePath), "Send your email in:"));
```

**emails** is the email

**subject** is the subject

**strAudioFilePath** is the mp4 path